# javaFX 2.0 set component to full width and height of immediate parent

Tags: java, javafx-2

How can I make a `TextArea` take the full width and height of the parent pane.

I tried this:

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
textArea.setScaleX( 100 );
textArea.setScaleY( 100 );
```

but the element defined in the top via `parent.setTop(...)` was covered.
Reducing the `scaleY` had no effect.

What else do I have to do to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

solved with this

```
textArea.setPrefSize( Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE );
```

Comment: I used this on a toolbar but it made the toolbar disappear :(

Comment: No, this doesn't work. Maybe it will work accidentially, but for sure this is not "the right way".

Comment: It worked for me by adding the node into a VBox and setting the width to Double.MAX_VALUE. For more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/size_align.htm

Answer (score 34):

The MAX_VALUE solution is a bit hacky and could cause performance issues. Also, the answer to this could depend on what your parent container is. Anyway, a better way to do it would be like this:

```
textArea.prefWidthProperty().bind(<parentControl>.prefWidthProperty());
textArea.prefHeightProperty().bind(<parentConrol>.prefHeightProperty());
```

You may also want to bind the preferred properties to the actual properties, especially if the parent is using it's computed dimensions rather than explicit ones:

```
textArea.prefWidthProperty().bind(<parentControl>.widthProperty());
textArea.prefHeightProperty().bind(<parentConrol>.heightProperty());
```

It's also possible to do this without using binding by overriding the layoutChildren() method of the parent container and calling

```
textArea.resize(getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Don't forget to call super.layoutChildren()...

Comment: How to set in `.fxml` file?

Comment: Was wondering as well how to set this in `.fxml`

Answer (score 5):

You achieve this by placing the `TextArea` in a `BorderPane`.

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setTitle("Resizing TextArea");

final BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
Scene scene = new Scene(border);

TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
textArea.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #aabbcc;");

border.setCenter(textArea);

primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.setVisible(true);
```

You can also place it inside an `HBox` or a `VBox`. Then resizing is limited to horizontal/vertical direction. Not sure if this is an issue.

Answer (score -2):

```
<TextArea style="-fx-pref-height: 10px;"/>
```

Answer (score -4):

you can do that with creating a css file.

```
textarea
{
width://your width
}
```